# Java - FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to decompress RAR archive on my Android device from the sd card but I got an error:

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
```

I chose a rar-file and try to decompress it in my sd-card.
Error says that it's not directory but it is. I have no idea how I can fix it.

My code:

```
public static void unrar(File srcRarFile, String destPath, String password) throws IOException {
    if (null == srcRarFile || !srcRarFile.exists()) {
        throw new IOException(".");
    }
    if (!destPath.endsWith(SEPARATOR)) {
        destPath += SEPARATOR;
    }
    Archive archive = null;
    OutputStream unOut = null;
    try {
        archive = new Archive(srcRarFile, password, false);
        FileHeader fileHeader = archive.nextFileHeader();

        while(null != fileHeader) {
            if (!fileHeader.isDirectory())
            {
                // 1  destDirName  destFileName
                String destFileName = "";
                String destDirName = "";

                destFileName = (destPath + fileHeader.getFileNameW()).replaceAll("/", "\\\\");
                destDirName = destFileName.substring(0, destFileName.lastIndexOf("\\"));

                // 2


                File dir = new File(destDirName);
                if (!dir.exists() || !dir.isDirectory()) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }
                //


                // ERROR:
                unOut = new FileOutputStream(dir);

                archive.extractFile(fileHeader, unOut);

                unOut.flush();
                unOut.close();
            }
            fileHeader = archive.nextFileHeader();
        }
        archive.close();
    } catch (RarException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(unOut);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clear thing. You first create the directory `/mnt/sdcard` (variable `dir` is equal to `destDirName` in your code) and then you try to create a file with the same same. This will not work. Use a name like `/mnt/sdcard/abc.rar` and it might work. Here is how you create the corresponding File object:

```
File file = new File(dir, "abc.rar");
```

Btw: creating a directory called `/mnt/sdcard` will probably not work due to a lack of permissions. If it's an SD card, Android will do this job for you anyway. If it isn't an SD card, its not a good idea to create a directory with this name.

PS2: After further reviewing your code I see things which are not good style:

1. You are using the separater variable and `indexOf`/`substring` to find the parent directory.
2. You replace "/" (the android path separator) by "\" which is only used in Windows
3. You swap between `File` and `string`

You can simply get rid of all this by using `File.getParent()`/`File.getParentFile()`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have set permissions in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```